# A question of the book Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading the book [Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras: Volume 1](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=SKC79Pt_c9EC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=view+modules+as+vector+spaces+connected+by+linear+maps&source=bl&ots=98TNbEboNe&sig=u76Bt1fsLn4DEOh75-9vyerhe9g&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ei=_AA3Uci_GOrKmgXdi4GwDQ&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=view%20modules%20as%20vector%20spaces%20connected%20by%20linear%20maps&f=false) .

I have a question on page 9, line -3 ([see Page 9 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6aLE.png)). It is said that $$h_1f_X = f_Y h_2.$$ 
I am trying to prove this. We have maps $h_1f_X: Xe_2 \to Xe_1 \to Ye_1$ and $f_Yh_2: Xe_2 \to Ye_2 \to Ye_1$. Let $xe_2 \in X_2$, where $x\in X$. Then $f_X(xe_2) = xe_2e_{21}e_1$. But what is the value of $h_1(xe_2e_{21}e_1)$? How to compute $h_1f_X(xe_2)$ and $f_Yh_2(xe_2)$ and show that they are equal? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe post your answer as an answer and accept it, so that the question is not shown as unanswered.

Comment: @Julian, thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fact that $h$ is an A-module homomorphism we have $h_1f_X(xe_2)=h_1(xe_2e_{21}e_1)=h(x)e_2e_{21}e_1$ and $f_Yh_2(xe_2)=f_Y(h(x)e_2)=h(x)e_2e_{21}e_1$.